# Repair-VirtualDisk remains in suspended

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

We erroneously added a P40 disk to our (marketplace) Azure Sql server / virtual machine.

We tried removing it following the process described in following articales

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/948241/storage-spaces-direct-cant-remove-physical-disk-fr

[Storage Spaces with Azure Disk: how can we extend virtual disks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1117638/storage-spaces-with-azure-disk-how-can-we-extend-virtual-disks)

We managed to get the Physical disk in a "Retired" state.
[image]

But after running "Repair-VirtualDisk -Friendlyname ", the job was added in a suspended state. And doesn't seem to run
[image]

Comment: This is not a question about Azure, this is a question about Storage Spaces. BTW, the answer is "no", you can't remove a 2-TB disk from a 3-TB volume.

Comment: Can we shrink the volume back down to 1TB somehow? @Massimo
Updated the tags.